# Derivative formula

Tags: co.combinatorics, differential-calculus

While trying to understand a paper of Cayley, he left something unexplained, I managed to show that it is equivalent to the following formula, which I got stuck at:

$$k \cdot (f^k)^{(k-1)} = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} {{k} \choose {j}} (f^{j})^{(j)}(f^{k-j})^{(k-j-1)}. $$

Can somebody help?

Comment: Do you want to know which functions satisfy this equation for some $k$, or for all $k$, or something else?

Comment: it should be true for any function (for simplicity lets say analytic)

Comment: Assuming it's true (I haven't checked), it ought to be enough just to prove it for powers $f(x) = x^n$. Have you checked it in that case?

Comment: why is it enough? the equation is not linear.

Comment: Okay, what I'm trying to say is that we only have to look at the Taylor expansion (at a point $x_0$) of $f^k$ up to order $k$; higher terms can be disregarded to show equality at $x_0$. So I was suggesting just checking the identity at polynomials; that should be enough.

Comment: True, but I don't know how to do that for polynomials.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed.  Experiment with Maple shows that the formula holds when $k=9$ and $f$ is a polynomial of degree $10$, and this is big enough to convince me that it must be true in general.  However,  I do not see any obvious proof.

Comment: @NeilStrickland I agree. I expect there would be a nice combinatorial interpretation as well. Do those who voted to close consider it obvious? It looks similar to a Leibniz product formula for higher derivatives, but I don't see how it follows trivially.

Comment: I also don't see why this was closed.

Comment: See Warren P. Johnson, The Pfaff/Cauchy derivative identities and Hurwitz type extensions, The Ramanujan Journal 13 (2007) pp. 167–201, http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11139-006-0246-0, or my survey paper on Lagrange inversion, Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A 144 (2016)  pp. 212–249, https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05988, section 2.6.

Comment: Which paper of Cayley?

Comment: @IraGessel That's great -- would you be able to make this into an answer, now that it's been reopened?

Comment: Yes, I will make it into an answer and add a few more details.

Comment: Isn't it possible to derive this from Faà di Bruno's formula?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A detailed historical discussion of identities like this one can be found in Warren P. Johnson's paper *[The Pfaff/Cauchy derivative identities and Hurwitz type extensions](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11139-006-0246-0)*, The Ramanujan Journal 13 (2007) pp. 167–201.
In particular, his formula (1.3) is
$$\frac{d^n\ }{dx^n} \phi^n(x) u(x) v(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk \left(\frac{d^k\ }{dx^k} \phi^k(x) u(x)\right)
 \left(\frac{d^{n-k-1}}{dx^{n-k-1}}\phi^{n-k}(x) v'(x)\right)\tag{1}\label{1}$$
where for $n=k$, $\frac{d^{n-k-1}}{dx^{n-k-1}}\phi^{n-k}(x) v'(x)$ is to be interpreted as $v(x)$. This identity was given by Cauchy in 1826, but is equivalent to an identity given by Pfaff in 1795.

The OP's identity is equivalent to the case $\phi(x)=f$, $u(x)=1$, $v(x) = x$.

There is a related formula in Cayley's paper *On the partitions of a polygon*, Coll. Math. Papers 13 (1897), 93–113; Proc. London Math. Soc. (1) 22 (1891), 237–262, but I didn't see this formula there.

Formulas like \eqref{1} are discussed in
my survey paper *[Lagrange Inversion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05988)*, Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A 144 (2016), pp. 212–249, section 2.6.

There is also a discussion of a somewhat related formula on Terry Tao's blog at [Another problem about power series](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/10/23/another-problem-about-power-series).

*Added November 12, 2022:* A new paper with multivariable generalizations of these identities is Wenchang Chu, [Multiple derivative inversions and Lagrange-Good expansion formulae](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/10/22/4234) ([DOI](https://doi.org/10.3390/math10224234) is being registered), Mathematics 10 (2022), 4234.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to Ira Gessel's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/262215), let me explain how such Pfaff–Cauchy–Hurwitz type identities are connected to polynomial interpolation techniques and to Raney lemma.

Denote $\mathbf k=\{1,\dotsc,k\}$.

We prove a more general (not polynomial in $f$, but multilinear in $f_1,\dotsc,f_k$) identity
$$
k(f_1\dotsm f_k)^{(k-1)}=\sum_{\emptyset\ne A\subset\mathbf k}\left(\prod_{i\in A} f_i\right)^{(\lvert A\rvert-1)}\left(\prod_{i\notin A} f_i\right)^{(n-\lvert A\rvert)}.
$$
It suffices to prove this identity when all $f_i$'s are power functions $f_i(t)=t^{x_i}$ (by some standard abstract nonsense). In this case we get a polynomial identity in $x_i's$ (where we denote $(x)_n=x(x-1)\dots(x-n+1)$, and also denote $s(A)=\sum_{i\in A}x_i$):
$$
k(s(\mathbf k))_{k-1}=\sum_{A\sqcup B=\mathbf k,A\ne \emptyset}(s(A))_{\lvert A\rvert-1}\,(s(B))_{\lvert B\rvert}.
$$
Both parts are polynomials of degree at most $k-1$, and it suffices to check that they coincide on the following combinatorial simplex $\Delta$: $x_i$ take non-negative integral values such that $\sum x_i\leqslant k-1$.

Note that for any $(x_1,\dotsc,x_k)\in \Delta$ and any partition $\mathbf k=A\sqcup B$, $A\ne \emptyset$, we have $s(A)+s(B)=s(\mathbf k)\leqslant k-1$, thus either $s(A)<\lvert A\rvert-1$ or $s(B)<\lvert B\rvert$ or $s(A)=\lvert A\rvert-1$, $s(B)=\lvert B\rvert$, $s(\mathbf k)=k-1$. Thus if $s(\mathbf k)<k-1$ both parts vanish, and if $s(\mathbf k)=k-1$, we have to prove that
$$
k!=\sum_{A:s(A)=\lvert A\rvert-1} (\lvert A\rvert-1)! (k-\lvert A\rvert)!
$$
I know this identity from Andrei Zelevinsky (2008). His manuscript [A peculiar algebraic identity](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506174935/http://mathserver.neu.edu/%7Ezelevinsky/identity021408.pdf) contains a clever proof both of combinatorial and falling factorials identities. Andrei asked not to circulate this text, but I think that this request is out of date….

Consider a permutation $\pi=(c_1,\dotsc,c_k)$ of $1,2,\dotsc,k$. Choose minimal $m$ for which $s(\{c_1,\dotsc,c_m\})<m$. Then by minimality $s(\{c_1,\dotsc,c_m\})=m-1$. For how many permutations did we have $\{c_1,\dotsc,c_m\}=A$, where $A$ is a fixed subset of $\mathbf k$ with $s(A)=\lvert A\rvert-1$? The answer is $(\lvert A\rvert-1)!\lvert B\rvert!$, since for any fixed cyclic order $(c_1,\dotsc,c_m)$ of $A$ exactly one out of $m$ permutations $(c_{i+1},c_{i+2},\dotsc,c_i)$ satisfies $s(c_{i+1},\dotsc,c_{i+t})\geqslant t$ for all $t=1,2,\dotsc,m-1$. This is a variant of Raney's lemma. Thus the identity.

We may avoid combinatorial arguments with Raney's lemma and remain entirely in algebra. The following trick is suggested by Vlad Volkov: we instead check the points for which  $(x_1,\dotsc,x_{k-1},x_k+1)\in \Delta$. In this case $\sum x_i\in \{-1,0,1,\dotsc,k-2\}$ and LHS equals 0 unless $x_1=\dotsb=x_{k-1}=0$, $x_k=-1$. In this last case LHS equals $(-1)^{k-1}k!$. Check the same for RHS. Always either $s(A)<\lvert A\rvert-1$ or $s(B)<\lvert B\rvert=k-\lvert A\rvert$, thus if the corresponding summand in RHS is non-zero, one of the sets $A$, $B$ has a sum of $x$'s equal to $-1$, i.e., consists of $k$ and several indices $i$ such that $x_i=0$. After some calculations everything reduces to Vandermonde–Chu identity.

Now a bit about multidimensional interpolation. Consider the space $\Pi(n,k)$ of polynomials $f(x_1,\dotsc,x_k)$ with degree at most $n$. Its dimension equals the number of monomials $x_1^{c_1}\dotsm x_k^{c_k}$, where $c_i$ are non-negative integers such that $\sum c_i\leqslant n$, we write this as $(c_1,\dotsc,c_k)\in \Delta_n^k$. Thus if we manage to find $\lvert\Delta_n^k\rvert$ linearly independent linear forms on $\Pi(n,k)$, then the polynomial $f\in \Pi(n,k)$ is uniquely determined by the values of these forms. I claim that the values at points of $\Delta_n^k$ serve as such linear forms. For proving that they are linearly independent we may simply construct a polynomial from $\Pi(n,k)$ which vanishes at all points of $\Delta_n^k$ but the given point $(t_1,\dotsc,t_k)$. Here it comes:
$$\prod_{i=1}^k \prod_{j=0}^{t_i-1}(x_i-j)\cdot \prod_{\ell=t_1+\dotsb+t_k+1}^n (x_1+\dotsb+x_k-\ell).$$

Comment: This looks really neat, but can you remind us why it suffices to check that identity on $\Delta $ ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I explained, there are many other explanations. See also a more general form of this lemma (Observation 2.2) here: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40879-016-0099-z
with several applications in spirit of the hook length formula

Comment: Ah! That's a beautiful identity; I expected some boring induction argument.. The identity you attribute to Zelevinsky, on the other hand, I remember seeing in a math contest (SPbMO?); maybe it was him who proposed it there?

Comment: @darijgrinberg yes, I asked him to use it on SPbMO and he kindly agreed

Comment: Ah :) By the way, has there been any progress on getting the problems and solutions (for SPbMO and 239MO) published in English? I remember that even finding the Russian version (from outside of Russia) was a challenge back when I was studying for contests...

Comment: I do not know about any progress. I may give you pdf's with problems and solutions in Russian if you e-mail me.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions of the Leibnitz rule to fractional calculus were investigated by Osler in the 1970s. See, e.g., "[Fractional derivatives and special functions](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1018042?journalCode=siread)" by Lavoie, Osler, and Tremblay.

One can even make expansions of the type

$$D^{-1} f(x)g(x) = (D_L+D_R)^{-1} f(x)g(x) = D_L^{-1}(1+D_R/D_L)^{-1}f(x)g(x)$$

$$ = \sum_{n \geq 0} \binom{-1}{n} [D^{-n-1}f(x)][D^ng(x)]= \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n [D^{-n-1}f(x)][D^ng(x)]$$

for some classes of functions with, e.g., $D^{-1}f(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$ and the subscripts on $D$ designating action on either the Left or Right factor.

For example, let $f(x) = x^{q-r}$ and $g(x) = x^{p+r}$ . Then

$$D^{-1}f(x)g(x) = D^{-1}x^{p+q} = \frac{x^{p+q+1}}{p+q+1}$$

and

$$\sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n [D^{-n-1}f(x)][D^ng(x)] = \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n [D^{-n-1}x^{q-r}][D^nx^{p+r}]$$

$$ =x^{p+q+1} \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n \frac{(q-r)!}{(q-r+n+1)!} \frac{(p+r)!}{(p+r-n)!} ,  $$

so the generalized Leibnitz rule holds in this case with the generalized integration $D^{-1} \frac{x^s}{s!} = \frac{x^{s+1}}{(s+1)!}$ for $x >0$ when

$$\frac{1}{p+q+1} =\sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n \frac{(q-r)!}{(q-r+n+1)!} \frac{(p+r)!}{(p+r-n)!} $$

which is valid for $p+q +1 > 0$

(see p. 268 in Section 105 of Die Gammafunktion by Niels Nielsen for convergence of this sum).

Comment: See also pages 277-8 of Integral Transforms and Their Applications (Second Edition) by Lebnath and Bhatta.